# Printing PDF using lp results in toner not adhering to paper

Tags: macos, cups, lp

Printing 7433c27f.pdf using `lp` results in toner not adhering to paper.

```bash
lp -o media=4x6 /Users/sunknudsen/Downloads/Superbacked/7433c27f.pdf
```

[image: 7433c27f.pdf]

Strangely enough, printing same PDF using “Preview” app on macOS works fine (using “File” / “Print…” menu item).

Ideas?

Comment: Same media in both cases?  Not same media *setting*, same media?   What printer?

Comment: Both printed on HP LasetJet P1102w, same paper… theoretically using same settings (postcard size), but somehow when printing via `lp`, printer appears to apply more toner (density appears higher).

Comment: The issue is not present when conducting same experiment while printing to Brother HL-L2370DW.

Answer (score 0):

Toner not adhering is a faulty or end-of-life fuser unit.

As to why it only shows when printing via `lp` -- it may be that the default settings for the printer are more prone to display the problem than those used in the GUI.

Compare the default characteristics that `lp` uses with the print settings in the print menu.

HP Printers usually have a control panel or web interface where you can set parameters, which may include the fuser temperature (something like Low, Normal, High).

Comment: Thanks for helping out… everything prints absolutely fine when using GUI.

Comment: @sunknudsen How many pages since you changed the fuser?

Comment: I purchased printer used… so unfortunately I don’t know.